# Как вывести вариации товара по attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
$args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'posts_per_page' => 100,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
        'post_status'   => array( 'publish' ),
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
    );
    $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        // get variation ID
        $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

        // get variations meta
        $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );

        // get variation featured image
        $variation_image = $product_variation->get_image();

        $variation_link = $product_variation->get_permalink();
        //get variation name
        $variation_name = $product_variation->get_variation_attributes();

        $fasovka = [ 'attribute_pa_paint' => $variation_name [ 'attribute_pa_paint'] ];
        if (($variation_name[attribute_pa_scale]=="1-24")&&(strpos($variation_image, '_G_1-18') !== false)) { 
            echo  '<a href="'.$variation_link.'">'.$variation_image.'</a><br>';
         }
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Данный код выводит все вариации товаров.

Но сейчас выводятся вариации с значением атрибута painted и unpainted. Мне нужно выводить только вариации содержащие значение атрибута painted.

Как это правильно сделать?

Атрибут paint имеет в себе значение painted и unpainted

Comment: а if не работает?

Comment: @splash58 Работает, но очень долго грузит страницу, так как проверяются все вариации.
Я хотел уменьшить количество итераций

Comment: @splash58 Я знаю что можно через metakey это сделать, но у меня почему-то не получается

Comment: думаю, кто знает wordpress подскажут, но, наверняка, можно указать в отборе условие на атрибут

Comment: У вас долго грузится из-за того, что 100 товаров = 100 запросов (но на самом деле get_post делает порядка 6 запросов в одном). После того как вы получили пост вы делаете WC_Product_Variation += 100 запросов (тоже самое про 6 запросов).

Comment: Опишите задачу, я напишу предложу нормальное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `wc_get_products` c параметром `type => variable` - это сократит вам кол-во запросов в несколько раз:

```
$products = wc_get_products( [
    'status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => -1,
    'type' => 'variable'
] );
```

Для того, чтобы получить нужный атрибут у `WC_Product` (также и `WC_Variation_Product`), есть метод `get_attribute( string $name );`

```
$product->get_attribute( 'painted' );
```

Но, скорее всего, атрибут будет называться pa_painted, т.к. стандартное именование аттрибутов начинается с приставки `pa_`.

Что касается написания своего запроса, то в нём нет смысла т.к. вам кроме аттрибутов, нужны данные товара. Данные всех аттрибутов будут получены при запросе `wc_get_products`.

Еще стоит подумать над лимитом. Если действительно задача требует лимита `-1`, то стоит задуматься над кеширование ваших запросов.

Например:

```
$products = get_transient( 'my_amazing_variation_products' );
if ( false === $products ) {
    $products = wc_get_products( [
        'status' => 'publish',
        'limit' => -1,
        'type' => 'variable'
    ] );
    set_transient( 'my_amazing_variation_products', $products, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
}
```